# How to handle HttpWebRequest redirect with non-ascii characters

Tags: httpwebrequest

I am writing an application that gets the server response code for a set of URLS by using the HttpWebRequest class. I came across a URL today that is causing me problems.

The problematic URL is http://blip.tv/file/5312019

When I load this URL in Internet Explorer, it correctly redirects me to **http://blip.tv/sorawut/money-talk-เม่า-นักเขียนการ์ตูนหุ้น-5329374**. But when using the HttpWebRequest class, it's having a problem redirecting.

If I set **AllowAutoRedirect** to false and examine the **Location** metatag in the response.Headers collection, it is showing the funky URL **http://blip.tv/sorawut/money-talk-à¹à¸¡à¹à¸²-à¸à¸±à¸à¹à¸à¸µà¸¢à¸à¸à¸²à¸£à¹à¸à¸¹à¸à¸«à¸¸à¹à¸-5329374**. When the request attempts to redirect to this URL, it causes an infinite redirect loop and ultimately ends up throwing a WebException saying "Too many automatic redirections were attempted".

I tried pasting this funky URL into Internet Explorer and it automatically changed it to the correct redirect URL and successfully loaded the page.

So, what do I need to do to have my HttpWebRequest return a status code of 200 for this particular URL? (Since it is a valid and active URL after a successful redirect)

Answer (score 1):

try this in your config file

```
<configuration>
   <uri>
     <idn enabled="All" />
     <iriParsing enabled="true" />
   </uri>
</configuration>
```

Look at the section **International Resource Identifier Support** here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx