# Windows Phone HttpWebRequest non ASCII Uri

Tags: windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

I've the same problem in that thread [How to handle HttpWebRequest redirect with non-ascii characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655574/how-to-handle-httpwebrequest-redirect-with-non-ascii-characters) and I've spend two days searching how to solve it but I really get no answer.
This is the exception message:
**[net_WebHeaderInvalidControlChars]
Arguments: Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.7.60408.0&File=System.Net.dll&Key=net_WebHeaderInvalidControlChars](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.7.60408.0&File=System.Net.dll&Key=net%5fWebHeaderInvalidControlChars)
Parameter name: name**

Could anyone help me please?

```
var wbr = WebRequest.CreateHttp(new Uri("http://www.10youtube.com/IowY8e6DaQIT-T53f8d4d6a64e6ec06e0b42a8c662cc05T-Tmp4T-TmediumT-T18TTT.mp4", UriKind.Absolute));
            wbr.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            wbr.Method = "GET";
            wbr.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
            wbr.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
            {
                var req = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
                var res = req.EndGetResponse(ar);
            }, wbr);
```

Comment: What's the URL for which you are testing? Can you please provide sample code too?

Comment: I've put a code snippet in post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try some :

```
     System.EscapeUriString()
```

Look at the documentation here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: The problem isn't with the requested url but is that it redirects to non ascii url